# Winnovative html to pdf converter for Azure function

Tags: azure, wkhtmltopdf, azure-appservice, winnovative

I want to apply winnovative html to pdf converter for one of my solution in azure function, but during installation it says use of Cloud service, which seems to be outdated. Do we install it using Azure App service?

Answer (score 2):

I took the liberty to download the latest version of the HtmlToPdf application, pushed it to [GitHub](https://github.com/sharpninja/HtmlToPdf), and deployed it to an Azure App Service (lowest tier, free).

You can see it running here: https://so-htmltopdf.azurewebsites.net/

I have also included the [Azure template for the App Service](https://github.com/sharpninja/HtmlToPdf/blob/main/AzureAppService.json), which includes the configuration for deploying directly from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Winnovative is a 3rd party tool, you'll need to use Virtual Machines or Containers, where you have control over the file system.

PS: You can run Azure Functions on Containers/ Virtual Machines using the official image.

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-base